# Dropdown not populated with data from an array when using jQuery.each() inside a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web3js

I have a simple single page website I am working on as part of an Ethereum dApp development course.
The web page is supposed to interact with Metamask and pull Ethereum addresses from a local test net created with Ganache, and then populate a dropdown field with the addresses. However this is not working.

I have Metamask set up with status Connected to the webpage. The page itself is a single HTML file which references a separate JavaScript file called "app.js" (stored locally in a /js folder) as well as Bootstrap CSS files. **The JavaScript file contains a function called populateAddress() which should get the accounts' addresses and append them to the dropdown list. This is what is not working.**

The dropdown section in the HTML file is below

```
<div class="row" id="address_div">
  <div style="margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 10px;">
    <span> Address : </span>
    <select id="enter_address" value="">
    </select>
  </div>
</div> 

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The populate function in app.js is below:

```
App = {
.
.
.
.    
    populateAddress : function(){
        new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(App.url)).eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
          jQuery.each(accounts,function(i){
            if(web3.eth.coinbase != accounts[i]){
              var optionElement = '<option value="'+accounts[i]+'">'+accounts[i]+'</option>';
              jQuery('#enter_address').append(optionElement);  
            }
          });
        });
      },
}
```

Comment: What does "not populating" mean? Did you debug any of your own code? Are you sure your populateAddress() method is getting called? Add debugging logging and figure out what lines of code aren't being executed.

Comment: Thanks Andy Ray. I just edited the title hopefully it makes it a bit clearer. The populateAddress() function should get the accounts' addresses and append them to the dropdown but that is not working. All I get is an empty dropdown element. Hope that makes more sense. I am not a JS expert so hoping for some help. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question (don't comment) with additional details. You haven't done any debugging, please be specific about where the code isn't working. Read up on `console.log` if you aren't familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing a string to **jQuery('#enter_address').append(optionElement);**   method while it needed **jquery element object.**

```
replace your line 

 var optionElement = '<option value="'+accounts[i]+'">'+accounts[i]+'</option>';

with this

 var optionElement = jQuery("<option/>",{value:accounts[i],text:accounts[i]});
```

below is a sample dropdown.

```js
var selectValues = {
  "1": "test 1",
  "2": "test 2"
};
var selctBox = $('#mySelect');
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
  var $option = $("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
  });
  selctBox.append($option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Negi Rox, but that didn't work for me. It appears the append() method can take a string too per link posted by Andy Ray.

Comment: for creating an option you should use an object instead of string.